# Communication between Controllers in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

I am learning iOS development using Obejctive-C for the last week now and I can't figure out how to communicate between controllers.
This is my storyboard:
[image]

The `Routes Page View Controller` is a `PageViewController` embedded inside the container view.

In the `MapViewController` I want to access the `RoutesPageViewController` to call some methods.
But when I make an outlet to the container view in my `MapViewController` and cast it to `RoutesPageViewController` and call a method it throws this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView items]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff60551a300'
```

Which is logic because it's not a `RoutesPageViewController`.

So my question is since I will encounter this issue in my further iOS development career: **What are the *good* ways to communicate between Controllers**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get the reference to the embedded view controller in `prepareForSegue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ContainerView is just a UIView. It doesn't have any reference of embedded ViewController. It creates a Parent-Child relationship between viewcontrollers. Like here, `MapViewController` is a parent and `RoutesPageViewController` is a child.

Now, for getting reference of child you should use `childViewControllers` property of `ViewController`. It will return an array of child ViewControllers.

Like here in `MapViewController`

```
let routeVC : RoutesPageViewController? = self.childViewControllers.filter{$0 is RoutesPageViewController}.first
```

will give you the reference of `RoutesPageViewController`.

Comment: so in for example `loadView` is a good place to set the propery?

Comment: No. not in loadView() . You can set the property in viewDidLoad of MapViewController.